# No module named _cffi_backend

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-cffi

I have Python 2.6 in my Linux rhel-5. I have installed pip and required CFFI packages. When I try to run a sample CFFI program:

```
ffi = FFI()
```

it says:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 56, in __init__
    import _cffi_backend as backend
ImportError: No module named _cffi_backend
```

What could be the possible error? Did I miss something during installation? I have installed pip, wheel, pycparser, pytest and cffi.

Answer (score 77):

For python2.x use following command:

```
python -m pip install cffi
```

for python3.x

```
python3 -m pip install cffi
```

Comment: I had to uninstall cffi first (`pip uninstall cffi`) and then reinstall again, because it said it was already installed

Answer (score 20):

I needed to uninstall and install it again:

```
sudo pip uninstall cryptography

sudo pip uninstall paramiko
```

then install pagamiko again

```
sudo pip install paramiko
```

and it start to work for me

Answer (score 16):

You have to first remove the following packages:

```
cryptography
bcrypt
paramiko
```

Now use the following command to install:

```
pip -vvv install --upgrade --force-reinstall cffi
```

Comment: this solution saved me bro <3

Comment: Just reinstalling did it for me. (ran into the error after downgrading fabric from 2.x to 1.x)

Comment: ''''pip -vvv install --upgrade --force-reinstall cffi'''' was enough for me

Answer (score 13):

I recently had the same issue and none of the above solutions worked for me.

Here is what worked.

```
sudo apt remove python3-cffi
sudo python3 -m pip install cffi
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, following this thread https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/4403, I solved the problem by reinstalling and upgrading with the command:

```
pip install -U cffi
```

Comment: Solution ofr me. Python 3.8.

Answer (score 9):

Did you compile Python from source, and if so, did it give you any errors during the `configure/make/make install` phase? Compiling Python from source can be a real beast on older Red Hat systems, so if you installed that way, I'd suggest combing through the `configure` and `make` output to be sure that no modules were left out.

In order to get `pip install cffi` to succeed with no errors, I had to install `gcc` and `libffi-devel` from the EL5 repos. From there, I was able to instantiate an FFI instance with no problems:

```
>>> from cffi import FFI
>>> ffi = FFI()
>>>
```

Here's the output of `pip freeze`, for reference:

```
[root@machine ~]# pip freeze
argparse==1.2.1
autobahn==0.8.10
cffi==1.5.2
characteristic==14.3.0
pika==0.9.13
pyasn1==0.1.7
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
pycparser==2.14
pycrypto==2.6.1
pyOpenSSL==0.12
pysnmp==4.2.5
requests==2.7.0
service-identity==14.0.0
six==1.7.3
Twisted==14.0.0
version-utils==0.2.2
wheel==0.24.0
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

If you've got the same or better versions of the relevant packages installed, I'd try a `pip -vvv install --upgrade --force-reinstall cffi`, just to see if there are perhaps errors that pip was masking, and go from there.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I have uninstalled the cffi and then installed it and it was solved:

```
pip uninstall cffi
pip install cffi
```

Answer (score 2):

Have the same problem. After many attempts adding import cffi solve the issue.

Make sure you have cffi and cryptography installed.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the code L56 in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cffi/api.py`

It needs the `_cffi_backend.so` in your pythonpath. You could install the python-cffi for it. But not sure whether it is in your RPM repo, especially you are using RHEL-5.
Here is an RPM for CENTOS `http://cbs.centos.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=20613`
Hope it helps. I am still searching the source code for building the `_cffi_backend.so`.

Answer (score 1):

For me there was no way to install cffi on python3.8 because of this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/__init__.py)
```

Somehow, the package `python3-distutils` does not exist in Ubuntu 16.04.

So I ended up installing **python3.7** and now I finally could install cffi, fixing the problem mentioned by the TS.

Comment: It was happening to me in a venv with Python 3.6 and I removed it and replaced it with a venv with Python 3.8 in my Ubuntu 20.04 and everything worked and all the problems were gone. Your answer inspired me to try a clean, radical solution. Thanks @Jurrian

Answer (score 1):

You should install cffi via `pip install cffi` 
to get the latest version. I had to restart my application for it to recognize the cffi installation.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while trying to get the cryptography module to work with Python 3.8 for AWS Lambda.

Adding the cffi*manylinux*.whl files to my Lambda Layer (as suggested [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/)) worked.

The cffi module comes built in for many python distributions, but not on AWS Lambda

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding the structure of your layer? like where you uncompress the whl file?

Answer (score 1):

For AWS Lambda I was facing the same issue when running on Python3.7. When I downgraded it to Python3.6, this issue was resolved.

I think this packaged might have been present in Python3.6 version and later was removed. Adding this package while making layers for AWS Lambda might resolve the problem for Python3.7.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue running an Ansible playbook using **python 3.9** under **Ubuntu-18.04** in **WSL2**. It was sorted by doing:

```
sudo apt-get remove -y python3-cffi-backend

sudo apt-get install -y python3-cffi-backend
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when trying to install packages in a local directory using `pip install -t .` and then running python (2.7). My solution was to remove the `-t` and not install into a local directory.

Answer (score 0):

it worked after adding  " import cffi " in my application.

please refer for more details.
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/cffi/latest/cffi.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@MPlanchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2351010/mplanchard), for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35656244/1151625) which helped identify the cause

In my case, the issue was related to python3.9, changing to python3.8 it just works well!

Answer (score 0):

After many futile efforts to install the right packages, the right python versions and building the perfect layer, resorting to installing Fabric solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved by

```
pip3.10 install cairocffi
```

Answer (score 0):

In Asus router the solution was:

```
opkg install python3-cffi
```