# Exe built with cx_Freeze shows error when containing pysftp import

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, pysftp

I am trying to compile an executable from a python script that uses pysftp. I'm using cx_Freeze to do that.

Here is my code:

`Test.py`

```
import datetime
import time
import os
import pysftp

i = 0
while(i<10):
    tm = datetime.datetime.now()
    print (tm.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
```

Here is the setup:

`setup.py`

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None    

executables = [Executable("Test.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna", "datetime", "time", "os", "pysftp"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {    
        'packages':packages,
    },    
}

setup(
    name = "<any name>",
    options = options,
    version = "<any number>",
    description = '<any description>',
    executables = executables
)
```

When I run `test.py` from the command line, it works fine. But when I run the exe that is built after running the command `python setup.py build`, `test.exe` fails and displays this:

```
C:\Users\cb\Desktop\Python Scripts\Test cx_Freeze install\build\exe.win-amd64-3.7>Test.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\cb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 23, in run
    exec(code, {'__name__': '__main__'})
  File "Test.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "C:\Users\cb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\Users\cb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 90, in <module>
    from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key
  File "C:\Users\cb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\ed25519key.py", line 17, in <module>
    import bcrypt
  File "C:\Users\cb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bcrypt\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import _bcrypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
```

Any suggestions on what I should try?

I have already tried adding `"cryptography"` and `"paramiko"` to the packages list. I've looked online and found that I may have to explicitly state the lib I am using for cx_Freeze, but I am not sure what that is.

I'm using python 3.7.3-64bit and windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to add `"paramiko"` and `"bcrypt"` to the `packages` list in your `setup.py` script. If this still does not work, please post the new traceback you should get.

   EDIT: this does not solve the problem according to the OP.
2. Search for a file named `_cffi_backend*.*` in your `C:\Users\cb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages`, do you find anything?

   EDIT: according to [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57380196/8516269), there is file `[Python version]\Lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp37-win_amd64.pyd`, and copying this file manually to the `lib` directory next to the built executable solves the issue.

   You should be able to let cx_Freeze do this additional step automatically by modifying your `setup.py` script like this:

   ```py
   import _cffi_backend
   _cffi_backend_file = _cffi_backend.__file__
   include_files = [(_cffi_backend_file, 'lib')]
   options = {
       'build_exe': {
          'include_files': include_files,    
          'packages': packages,
       },    
   }
   ```

2nd EDIT:

3. Instead of the above proposals, try to simply add `_cffi_backend` to the `includes` list of the `build_exe` options in your `setup.py` script:

   ```py
   includes = ['_cffi_backend']
   options = {
       'build_exe': {
          'includes': includes,    
          'packages': packages,
       },    
   }
   ```

Comment: I tried adding "bcrypt" "paramiko" and "cryptography" but nothing seems to have changed. I looked in that path and there is a file named "_cffi_backend.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
Here is the trace back (pretty much same as before):
C:\Users\cb\Desktop\Python Scripts\Test cx_Freeze install\build\exe.win-amd64-3.7>Test.exe
...
  File "C:\Users\cb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bcrypt\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import _bcrypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'

Comment: What is the exact path of this file `cffi_backend.cp37-win_amd64.pyd`? What happens if you put of copy of it into `C:\Users\cb\Desktop\Python Scripts\Test cx_Freeze install\build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\lib` and/or into `C:\Users\cb\Desktop\Python Scripts\Test cx_Freeze install\build\exe.win-amd64-3.7` (after having built your executable)? Does the exe works then, or do you get a different error?

Comment: The cffi_backend file was in the same directory you said it would be in (c:\users\cb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cffi_backend.cp37-win_amd64.pyd). After I copied that file to the same directory that the exe was (python scripts\Test cx_Freeze install\build\exe.win-amd64-3.9) the built exe worked fine. Thank you! It also works if I drop it into the lib directory cx_freeze created. I'm curious why it didn't get copied or where the installer intended for that file to go.

Comment: @MocApocalypse Sounds great! I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MocApocalypse I also don't know why this file did not get copied. I'm curious, would it work if you would simply add `_cffi_backend` to the `includes` list of the `build_exe` options (see the new third option of my answer)?

Comment: Yes, explicitly adding _cffi_backend to the packages list also fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to [jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8516269/jpeg) for providing the great suggestions that led to help fixing this issue. What I had to do was to copy `_cffi_backend.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` to the `lib` directory next to the built executable.

You can find this file under your python install (`[Python version]\Lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp37-win_amd64.pyd`)